# Chinese Idiom puzzle 20 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Puzzle for June 2021

[image]

1. 「病從口入」下句
2. Lengthy article (or speech)
3. Asking a tiger for its skin (Make deal with dangerous people)
4. Busily run around or move around for a certain purpose
5. Bragging without shame
6. To do a good job, you must prepare your tools
7. Good at doing business
8. Act fast and reach the goal before the others
9. Sichuan Provincial's Capital
10. Step down after one's work is done
11. "White strip in the waves" 水滸傳中張順的綽號
12. Prophet
13. Degeneration of feudal religious rites
14. Unified
15. Dead end road in front, pursuing soldiers behind (desperate situation)
16. 陶渊明's story,  "Have a backbone, not submit oneself for material wealth"
17. a tiny portion of an enormous amount
18. Burn down the musical instrument to cook the crane (pay no respect for elegance)

19.「上天無路」下句 (Nowhere to run or hide)

20. public opinion
21. Like riding on the back of a tiger
22. Number one; top of the field
23. Become a hero at a young age
24. Hold high position in both political and military office
25. Demonstration

A. 「一代新人勝舊人」前句

B. You can do whatever you want

C. A scene in the Romance of the Three Kingdoms where 曹操 and 劉備  remarked on the other warlords of the time

D. Good deeds get good rewarded

E. Gone without a trace

F. The ulterior secret has been completely exposed

G. Elope

H. Fight to move ahead; afraid of falling behind

I. The strength of nine bulls and two tigers combine (enormous effort)

J. Long run

K. First come, first serve

L. Negotiate with the other party in a polite manner first and then use tough methods when it doesn’t work

M. Income is less than the expense

N. A Chinese mythical figure in ancient times, famous for his feat of flood control

O. Barren land

P. Describe someone who achieves success at a mature age.

Q. You like to do it, so why not?

R. Many different kinds

S. Prime minister

T. Unlike the others

U. Unruly and unseemly behavior

V. realized fact; can't be undone

W. Things are going through twists and turns, and it’s not easy

X. Instruction

Y. insincere fake laugh

Z. Describe someone with a lot of cash in his person

Answer (score 1):

1. 禍從口出
2. 長篇大論
3. 與虎謀皮
4. 東奔西跑
5. 大言不慚
6. 工欲善其事，必先利其器
7. 长袖善舞
8. 捷足先登
9. 成都
10. 功成身退
11. 浪裏白條
12. 先知
13. 禮崩樂壞
14. 統一
15. 前無退路，後有追兵
16. 不爲五斗米折腰
17. 九牛一毛
18. 
19. 入地無門
20. 輿論
21. 勢如騎虎
22. 首屈一指
23. 
24. 出將入相
25. 示威

A. 長江後浪推前浪
B. 從心所欲（a more popular version of this idiom would be 隨心所欲）
C. 煮酒論英雄
D. 善有善報
E.
F. 東窗事發
G. 私奔
H. 爭先恐後
I. 九牛二虎之力
J. 長跑
K. 先到先得
L. 先禮後兵
M. 入不敷出
N. 大禹
O. 不毛之地
P. 大器晚成
Q. 何樂而不爲
R. 五花八門
S. 首相
T. 與衆不同
U. 不成體統
V. 米已成炊（pun in Chinese for couples who xoxo-ed，other form: 生米煮成熟飯)
W. 一波三折
X. 指示
Y. 皮笑肉不笑
Z. 腰纏萬貫（this is actually a metaphor though）

Comment: More hints for you: for #7. You got 長 from 長江後浪推前浪. 䄂 was given, and you got 善 in 善有善報. So you already have 長䄂善?, Enter it to Google search and you will get 长袖善舞 for the top result.

Comment: 19. 走投無路 is wrong, the correct answer is 「上天無路」下句. I will add it to the hints list

Comment: Search the incomplete answers in Google could get you the full answer, for example, #13, you got 禮 in 先禮後兵, 崩 is given, so you got '禮崩??' already, enter it in Google and 禮崩樂壞 will be the top result and the correct answer. Now you got one more character for #Q, and 何樂??為's Google search will give you 何樂而不為